# Facebook image post permalink

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a system which posts stuff on facebook through their api. The problem I'm having is when trying to figure out the permalink of the post from the response I get from facebook.
The response from facebook looks like this:

```
{'id': 'some_numerical_id', 'post_id': 'id1_id2'} # id1 and id2 are two numerical ids separated by an underscore
```

Anybody know how I can figure out the permalink from this? 
I tried using

```
/permalink.php?story_fbid=x&id=y
```

But this doesn't work for posts containing pictures (didn't try with videos).